# If Checkbox checked conditional between pages

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I currently have a Checkbox under my settings.xaml page, which the users is to click to allow location services.

```
private void cbLocationAllow_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Location Services is now enabled");
}

private void cbLocationAllow_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Location Services is now disabled");
}
```

I have location aware bing map on the my MainPage which I would like to have check the status of the checkbox on settings.xaml before finding location.

I assume it would a condition if else, but im not quite sure how to implement this as the checkbox is on another page.

The below code was suggested to me, but I am getting errors on

```
Settings.SetSetting("allowLocation",true);
```

On settings page:

```
cbLocationAllowChecked(...)
{
Settings.SetSetting("allowLocation",true);
}

cbLocationAllowUnchecked(...)
{
Settings.SetSetting("allowLocation,false);
}
```

On main page as conditional

```
MapButtonClicked(...)
{
if (!Settings.HasSetting("allowLocation") || !((bool)Settings.GetSetting("allowLocation"))
        MessageBox.Show("Allow app to use your location?, "Location Services",MessageBoxButtons.OkCancel);
//handle result
else{

StartLocationSearch();
}

}
```

Any suggestions or links that would help me out would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: Use IsolatedStorageSettings if you want to persist the setting across invocations of your application. Otherwise, make it a global variable within your application class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`IsolatedStorageSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings%28VS.95%29.aspx) class to save your setting.

To store the setting

```
private void cbLocationAllow_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

  settings["allowLocation"] = true;
  settings.Save();
}
```

To read the setting

```
var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
bool allowLocation = false;

if( settings.Contains( "allowLocation" ) ) {
  allowLocation = (bool)settings["allowLocation"];
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error with `allowLocation = settings["allowLocation"];` message is cannot implicitly convert object to bool. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Rhys Oops, forgot to cast the read value, sorry. Updated the answer.